# Xcode: Collection view not displaying properly

Tags: xcode

I was working on app that would take some input from the user and put them into a collection view. The data goes to the database and retrieves successfully into a dictionary `movies`, but while displaying the collection view, it shows doesn't show the third item, but shows the second item twice. After re-running the app, the problem gets fixed. How do I fix this without having to re-run my app every time?

`movieCollectionView` is my UICollectionView, and `MovieCollectionViewCell` is my Cocoa Touch Class file for the collection view.

Comment: Can you try using `productCollectionView.reloadData()`  in the refresh button action? You need to check the contents of products array when you hit refresh vs when you re-run the app. It seems like your data source (products array) is not providing expected data in case of refresh function.

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix for the issue - Add following call inside `refreshBtn(_ sender: Any)` function.

```
productCollectionView.reloadData()
```

Other observation - You shouldn't need this line -

```
productCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
```